# Django query: Want to count a set in template

Tags: python, html, django, count

I have a list of item which only displays the latest status of each item. What I want to do now is count. Problem is that is the `count` function will only work properly if `latest` is removed - however that would give me something like this.

item1=1 item2=33 item3=12 item4=0

Basically it will count all statuses for that item, but it needs  focus on counting the latest status so the answer in this case should be 3. This is why I need the latest `latest`.
There is also a foreign key relationship between a storage item and status, an item can have many statuses or if not, no status at all.

```
#views.py
client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
items = client.storageitem_set.all()
```

template

```
{% for item in items %}
        {{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that all you need is the count of all items that have a status - rather than the count of all statuses related to your items. Is that right? If so, this will do it:

```
count = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id, itemstatushistory__isnull=False).count()
```

Comment: problem is that an item can have many status. I want to count an only the latest status. So for example, if an item has say - two statuses called `in` and `collected`. It need to just count collected status only.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You don't actually want to count the statuses at all, you want to count the items that have at least one status. That's what the above code does.

Comment: Oh I see the problem. What I meant by _count latest status_. This means for each item with more that one status - keep it is one. I think it may be resolved if there is a distinct function in your answer.